# CSS Selector not Selecting?

Tags: python, css, select, beautifulsoup

Why isn't my `s.select("li")` statement selecting the code? How can I get it to select it?

```
print type(s)
print s
if not s.select("li"): print 'lol!'
```

OUTPUT:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<li id="330811110-hlshE">1</li>
lol!
```

Answer (score 1):

`select()` searches *inside* the object (which can be a `Soup` object as well as a `Tag`) you call it on, and there's no `li` element inside `s` to find. This, on the other hand, works:

```
print type(t)
print t
print t.select("li")
if not t.select("li"): print 'lol!'

# outputs:
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<ul><li id="330811110-hlshE">1</li></ul>
[<li id="330811110-hlshE">1</li>]
```

If you want to test whether a `Tag` object **is** a particular element, rather than whether it contains one, just test its `name` attribute:

```
if s.name == "li": print "yep"

# outputs:
yep
```